# Simplest way to make a command run after system reboot

Tags: reboot, upstart, init.d, runlevel

I have a server which exists to run one little Django application. If the server reboots, I want Django to start again:

```
nohup /opt/myapp/manage.py runserver ...
```

I'm having trouble finding a simple way to make this run. There are tutorials explaining how to write full-fledged services, runlevels, init.d etc. But there must be a simpler way? A place where I can hack this one extra line onto?

EDIT Mark's answer is perfect, the one-liner works out as:

```
sudo sed --in-place '/^exit 0/i\cd /opt/appdir\npython manage.py runserver .... &' /etc/rc.local
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add it to `/etc/rc.local` before the line that says `exit 0`. This way it will run at boot every time.

To add the command using one line:

```
sudo sed --in-place '/^exit 0/i\cd /opt/appdir\npython manage.py runserver .... &' /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: Perfect. For anyone who wants to do this programmatically, here's the one-liner I came up with:

sudo sed --in-place '/^exit 0/i\cd /opt/appdir\nnohup python manage.py runserver ... &' /etc/rc.local

Comment: At shutdown the service will be "killed". Be carefull not doing that for services that needs a "clean" shutdown.